# Where does Tomcat creates it's logs

Tags: tomcat

My application is throwing exception : connection pool exhausted.I have  resolved it. But I would like to know how many times the error occurred in last week.

Please tell me where do such logs get created in tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Standard: in the log folder of your installed tomcat

Comment: True, but on Ubuntu it may be at `/var/log/tomcat[x]/` for instance when you installed Tomcat via `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tomcat installation directory and find `logging.properties` in the `conf` subdir. Here the logging paths are defined.

Usually when you have installed Tomcat 'manually', logs will be written to the directory `logs` under your Tomcat installation directory. When you use some package manager like on Ubuntu it may be at

```
var/log/tomcat[x]/
```

x being the version of Tomcat.

Look for a file named `Catalina.out` in one of the above folders.